# Does a low GPA in an unrelated (second) major affect math PhD admissions?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, gpa

I'm a second year undergrad in Canada, double majoring in math and philosophy. I take philosophy only because it is a spare time interest in high school, but I'm planning to apply math PhD after my undergrad study.

The problem now is that, my philosophy grade is overall 3.3(77-79, B+), though my math grade is 4.0(85+,A).

I'm wondering whether or not my philosophy grade will affect my math PhD application (targeting a top 20 program in North America)?

Comment: I've edited the secondary question you added later out of this post because the Q&A model works best when you ask [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1204/11365); but please feel free to ask the second question in a new, separate post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a math PhD program, the GPA in math is by far the most important.  Your overall GPA still counts for something, but GPA *in a different major* may not count for anything more: if you applied to my math PhD program (UGA), I don't think your philosophy GPA would specifically be considered by us.  If your overall GPA were something like 3.5 and your math GPA is 4.0: well, then you look like an overall good student who is outstanding at math.  That's what math PhD programs want!

Having said that: I note that (i) you intend to go to a math PhD program, (ii) you have a perfect(?) math GPA and a (perfectly respectable but) significantly lower GPA in your second major, and (iii) you describe your second major "as a spare time interest in high school".  I don't quite get it: you're not in high school anymore, so....tell me again why you're majoring in philosophy?